# Background of div gets cut off at viewport

Tags: css

I know that this is SIMILAR to a few questions already out there, but it's different in that it's not my main body background that's causing the problem, and so I'm lost.

The website is at http://www.thesweet-spot.com/test77

The problem is that when you shrink your viewport to be smaller than the content and then scroll down, the wavy line on the left stops at where the bottom of your viewport originally was. The tricky part is that I want the wavy line on the left to scroll WITH the content when the content is too long.

The relevant CSS looks like this:

```
body {
background: url('images/background.jpg');
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
min-width: 1000px;
}

#container {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 105px;
bottom: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#sidebarbg {
background: url('images/chocolate.jpg');
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
z-index: 11;
background-attachment:fixed;
}

#sidebar {
background: url('images/sidebar.png');
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
z-index: 12;
}

#contentnest {
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 365px;
right: 0;
z-index: 14;
}

#content {
background: url('images/contentbg.png');
-moz-border-radius: 30px;
-webkit-border-radius: 30px;
border-radius: 30px;
-khtml-border-radius: 30px;
padding: 20px;
border: #f062a4 3px solid;
width: 80%;
min-width: 350px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
font-size: 22px;
line-height: 150%;
font-family: QuicksandBook, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #905131;
}
```

and the HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
<div id="sidebarbg"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="contentnest">
<div id="content">
<! -- content goes here -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the BG of my absolute container to extend beyond the viewport by adding this to my div style that has the BG.

```
min-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

This will cause a double scroll bar so add this to your body style

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

in `#sidebar` try removing `height:100%` and add `bottom:-99999em`

the other way is to make the sidebar `position:fixed`.

Comment: When I tried the first solution, the whole sidebar div disappeared - presumably, it was -9999em below the bottom of the page. I tried adding top:0 to the equation, but that presented the same original issue.

I can't implement the second suggestion, because like I said, I want the waves to move up or down with the content scroll.

Comment: how about both top:0 and bottom:-9999em ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for being unclear. That's what I tried, but it presented with the same issue as setting height to 100%. If the viewport is smaller than the content, the BG gets cut off. I've just edited the content so it's longer than the viewport so you can see the issue. If you use Firebug or equivalent to set top to 0 and bottom to -9999em, you can see the issue persists.